# Cordova build failed, SDK Platform Component is missing

Tags: android, cordova, build

This is what I get when I run "cordova build" inside a created cordova project folder:

BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/tools/ant/build.xml:396: SDK Platform Tools component is missing. Please install it with the SDK Manager (tools/android)

And I have the SDK Platform installed.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK platform does not necessarily have the platform tools. From command line go to the directory

`\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools`

and download the tools by giving the following command

`android.bat update sdk --no-ui`

Type `y` to accept the license.